# USPS International Shipping not working all the sudden

Tags: ecommerce, brilliantretail

We did a site a while back and they have been shipping products all over the country as well as internationally.

They were able to ship something as recently as last month and now they are unable to get international shipping rates. It is saying "No Shipping Options Available".

I am using Brilliant Retail 1.0.2.5 and EE v2.1.3.

Comment: We've definitely fixed this in the latest versions of BR. Let me know if you are still having issues or are unable to update. Best, David

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @litzinger on Twitter

USPS came out with an updated API on July 28th the upgraded BR install seems to have this fixed I am going to be looking into updating this for the client so if you absolutely have to stay on the old version of BR like I do let me know.